# error in bs4 while fetch details in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using python and bs4 to scrape github data and I want to scrape a users stars using this function

```
def total_stars(username):
    try:
        html = requests.get('https://github.com/'+username).text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        total_commit = soup.select_one(
            '#js-pjax-container div.container-xl.px-3.px-md-4.px-lg-5 div div.flex-shrink-0.col-12.col-md-3.mb-4.mb-md-0 div div.js-profile-editable-replace div.d-flex.flex-column div.js-profile-editable-area.d-flex.flex-column.d-md-block div.flex-order-1.flex-md-order-none.mt-2.mt-md-0 div a:nth-child(3) span').text
        print(total_stars)
        return (total_commit)
    except:
        return (0)
```

this function was working before but now it is giving me error please if some knows the cause and how to fix it will be very helpful

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Thanks !

Comment: This is happening because Github's user page has changed layout since this code worked. Why not use the GitHub REST API instead of scraping HTML?

Answer (score 1):

When `soup.select_one()` can't find the element you are looking for, it returns `None`.

So your exception comes from this line(look at the `.text` at the end):

```
total_commit = soup.select_one(
            '#js-pjax-container div.container-xl.px-3.px-md-4.px-lg-5 div div.flex-shrink-0.col-12.col-md-3.mb-4.mb-md-0 div div.js-profile-editable-replace div.d-flex.flex-column div.js-profile-editable-area.d-flex.flex-column.d-md-block div.flex-order-1.flex-md-order-none.mt-2.mt-md-0 div a:nth-child(3) span').text
```

Webpage layouts may change any time.

Try to use id's as much as possible. They are unlikely to change (compare to other selectors).

Comment: how do i directly get ids in chrome's inspect element tab?

Comment: @stark Yes, find element there and see if it (or it's nearest parent) has id.

Comment: this is not working

Answer (score 0):

#### What happens?

Something strange in your sample code - Who you gonna call? ;) You are using a mix of variable names `total_commits`, `total_stars` and this heavy `css selector`, what is very confusing.

However the element you are try to select do not exists or could not be found and you could not call `.text` on a `None Type`

#### How to fix?

Keep it as simple as possible and locate your target by the `href` that contains `tab=stars` and select its `<span>`:

```
soup.select_one('a[href*="tab=stars"] span')
```

To avoid any `None Type` errors just check if element exists and get its text or set `total_stars` to 0:

```
total_stars = soup.select_one('a[href*="tab=stars"] span').text if soup.select_one('a[href*="tab=stars"] span') else 0
```

#### Example

```
def total_stars(username):
    
    html = requests.get(f'https://github.com/{username}').text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    total_stars = soup.select_one('a[href*="tab=stars"] span').text if soup.select_one('a[href*="tab=stars"] span') else 0

    return (total_stars)
    
total_stars('fabpot')
```

#### Output

```
188
```